# Limit of a sequence including infinite product. $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, products, infinite-product

I need to find the limit of the following sequence:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: Also duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183061/how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-prod-limits-k-1n-1k-n2?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **PRIMER:**
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1} \tag 1$$
>
> for $x>0$.

---

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^n \log\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Applying the right-hand side inequality in $(1)$ to $(2)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \log\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)&\le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2}\\\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2} \\\\
&=\frac12 +\frac{1}{2n}\tag 3
\end{align}$$

Applying the left-hand side inequality in $(1)$ to $(2)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \log\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)&\ge \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+n^2}\\\\
&\ge \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n+n^2}\\\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2(n^2+n)} \\\\
&=\frac12 \tag 4
\end{align}$$

Putting $(2)-(4)$ together yields

$$\frac12 \le \log\left(\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)\right)\le \frac12+\frac{1}{2n} \tag 5$$

whereby application of the squeeze theorem to $(5)$ gives

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty} \log\left(\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)\right)=\frac12}$$

Hence, we find that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)=\sqrt e}$$

And we are done!

Comment: That solution would be perfect for me if I knew anything about that 'O' symbol. My lecturer has not defined it yet, so there comes my question: is there any slightly less difficult solution? However, thank you for that one.

Comment: Have you learned Taylor's Theorem?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. I'm just at the beginning of my studies.

Comment: @R.K. I've edited the development given your feedback.  The development relies on basic tools only now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mister! Now I get all the steps of that solution.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: Actually, after rethinking, I have one question according to the step number 4. Why is k/(k+n^2) greater than k/(1+n^2)? The denominator of the second fraction is smaller than the first one's, so shouldn't it be <?

Comment: @r.k. Yes, good catch.  I've edited.

Comment: (+1) It seems that you are pretty good with the knife :D

Comment: @marcocantarini Marco, thanks.  And once in a while, I'll bring heavIer weaponry

Answer (score 7):

Note that $$\prod_{k\leq n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n^{2}}\right)=\prod_{k\leq n}\left(\frac{n^{2}+k}{n^{2}}\right)=\frac{\left(n^{2}+1\right)_{n}}{n^{2n}}
 $$ where $\left(x\right)_{m}
 $ is the [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) and since $$\left(x\right)_{m}=\frac{\Gamma\left(x+m\right)}{\Gamma\left(x\right)}
 $$ we have $$\prod_{k\leq n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n^{2}}\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(n^{2}+n+1\right)}{n^{2n}\Gamma\left(n^{2}+1\right)}\longrightarrow\color{red}{\sqrt{e}}
 $$ where the last limit can be calculated using the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Bringing a gun to a knife fight.  (+1)

Comment: @Dr.MV Well, in a battle of the fittest, the gun usually wins... unless you are some amazing hero that saves us all :D

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

$$P_n=\prod_{k=1}^n (1+\frac{k}{n^2})\implies \log(P_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \log\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)$$ Work with the sum (without forgetting by the end that $P_n=e^{\log(P_n)}$)

Comment: Allo Claude!  Comment allez vous?  (+1)

Answer (score 5):

$$\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2} \right)\left(1+\frac{n-k}{n^2} \right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{n} +\frac{k(n-k)}{n^4} \right)$$

Then we have
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}  \right) \leq \left(1+\frac{1}{n} +\frac{k(n-k)}{n^4} \right) \leq \left(1+\frac{1}{n} +\frac{1}{n^2} \right)=\left(1 +\frac{n+1}{n^2} \right)$$

Therefore
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}  \right) ^\frac{n}{2} \leq  \prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right) \leq \left(1 +\frac{n+1}{n^2} \right)^\frac{n}{2}$$

and squeeze it.

Comment: @Dr.MV Forgot the product sign, fixed, ty.