# Prove the convergence of $\prod\limits^{n}_{k=1}{\left(1+\frac{k}{n^p}\right)} $ and Find Its Limit

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

> Suppose $p> 1$ and the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ has a general term of
>   $$x_n=\prod\limits^{n}_{k=1}{\left(1+\frac{k}{n^p}\right)} \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space n=1,2,3, \cdots$$
>   Show that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges, and hence find
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{x_n}$$
>   which is related to $p$ itself.

I have been attempted to find the convergence of the sequence using ratio test but failed. The general term has a form of alike the $p$-series. And also the question seems difficult to find its limit because the denominator is of $p^{th}$ power. How do I deal it?

Comment: There's no way it converges when $p=1$

Comment: What if the case for $p>1$? I have edited the question.

Comment: $\log(x_n) \le \sum_{k=1}^n \log(1+\frac{k}{n^p}) \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^p} = \frac{1}{2}n^{2-p}$, which goes to $0$ if $p > 2$. Idk about $1 < p \le 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\prod\limits^{n}_{k=1}{\left(1+\frac{k}{n^p}\right)}=e^{\sum^{n}_{k=1}{\log \left(1+\frac{k}{n^p}\right)}}$$

and

$$\sum^{n}_{k=1}{\log \left(1+\frac{k}{n^p}\right)}=\sum^{n}_{k=1} \left(\frac{k}{n^p}+O\left(\frac{k^2}{n^{2p}}\right)\right)=$$$$=\frac{n(n-1)}{2n^{p}}+O\left(\frac{n^3}{n^{2p}}\right)=\frac{1}{2n^{p-2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{2p-3}}\right)$$

therefore the sequence converges for $p\ge 2$

- for $p=2 \implies x_n \to \sqrt e$
- for $p>2 \implies x_n \to 1$

and diverges for $1<p<2$.

Refer also to the related

- [Limit of a sequence including infinite product. $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2052624/505767)
- [How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty} \prod\limits_{k=1}^n (1+k/n^2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/183061/505767)

Comment: How do you attempt $\sum\limits^{n}_{k=1}{\log {(1+\frac{k}{n^p})}^{n^p}}$~$\frac{n^2}{2}$?

Comment: For n large $(1+k/n^p)^{n^p}\to e^k$ and $\sum k=n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: @weilam06 In my answer I've given the key fact to find a complete solution, I can add some more detail to make thinkg more clear and rigorous.

Comment: That's okay. I understand that $\frac{1}{2n^{p-2}}$ is a $p-$series.

Comment: @weilam06 That'snice. I've just modified a little bit the key step in a more precise way! Bye