# Quick question about the Product Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure

I came across the following identity
$$
\lim_{\Delta x\Delta t\to 0}\prod_{x,t\in A}(1-f(x,t) \Delta x\Delta t)=\exp\left(-\int\int_{x,t\in A}f(x,t)\, dxdt\right)
$$
where $A$ is some subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is this true?

**Thoughts:** This seems to be a [type I Volterra product integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral#Type_I:_Volterra_integral_2). On the linked page, we have
$$
\prod_X \big(1 + f(x) \,d\mu(x)\big) = \exp \left( \int_X f(x) \,d\mu(x) \right)
$$
In our case, $\mu$ would be a Lebesgue measure and we could simply redefine $f(x,t)\equiv -f(x,t)$. However, is the Lebesgue measure here well defined? Perhaps it's just a matter of notation ($\Delta x, \Delta y$ can be interpreted the same as $dxdt$), or am I missing some important detail?

Comment: Quick answer: $\iint_{x,t\in A}f(x,t)\,dx\,dt=\lim\limits_{\Delta x\Delta t\to 0}\sum\limits_{x,t\in A}f(x,t)\,\Delta x\,\Delta t\,.$ Now use $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$ and $e^{-c}\approx 1-c$ for small $c\,.$

Answer (score 2):

I tried to make sense of the product integrals as given by the OP and the link he provided.  I can prove the statement for functions $f$ that are Riemann integrable in some box $C=[a,b]\times[c,d]\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ as follows.

Let $\mathcal{P}:=\{[t_i,t_{i+1}]\times[s_j,s_{j+1}]: 0\leq I< n, 0\leq j< m\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ ($a=t_0<\ldots<t_n=b$, $c=s_0<\ldots<s_m=d\}$. Assume $|f(\mathbf{x})|\leq M$, for all $\mathbf{x}\in C$. Then for any $A\in\mathcal{P}$, choose a tag $\mathbf{x}_A\in A$ and define
$$Q_{\mathcal{P}}=\prod_{A\in\mathcal{P}}\big(1+f(\mathbf{x}_A)\lambda_2(A)\big)$$
where $\lambda_2([t_i,t_{i+1}]\times[s_j,s_{j+1}])=(t_{i+1}-t_i)(s_{j+1}-s_j)$ if $A=[t_i,t_{i+1}]\times[s_j,s_{j+1}]$.

Suppose partitions $\mathcal{P}_k$ are taken so that $\max_{A\in\mathcal{P}_k}\lambda_2(A)=0$.

Then

- $\max_{A\in\mathcal{P}_k}|f(\mathbf{x}_A)\lambda_2(A)|\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}0$
- $\lim_k\sum_{A\in\mathcal{P}_k}f(\mathbf{x}_A)\lambda_2(A)=\int_Cf$
- $\sup_k\sum_{A\in\mathcal{P}_k}|f(\mathbf{x}_A)|\lambda_2(A)\leq M\lambda_2(C)$

Then, $\lim_kQ_{P_k}=\exp\Big(\int_Cf\Big)$. This follows from  Theorem A below. The result can be extended to Riemann integrable functions over bounded closed boxes on $\mathbb{R}^d$. For more general functions, for example, Lebesgue integrable the statement in the OP may not hold.

> **Theorem A:**
> Let  $\{c_{n,m}:1\leq m\leq m_n\}\subset\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that
>
> 1. $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow0}\sup_{1\leq m\leq m_n}|c_{n,m}|=0$,
> 2. $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum^{m_n}_{m=1}c_{n,m}=c\in\mathbb{C}$,
> 3. and $M:=\sup_n\sum^{m_n}_{m=1}|c_{n,m}|<\infty$.
>    Then
>    \begin{align}\prod^{m_n}_{m=1}(1+c_{n,m})=e^c
>    \end{align}

A proof pot this result can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4840415/121671)